# How to get glutTimerFunct to call a child classes function

Tags: c++, opengl, inheritance

So I am trying to make a project that mirrors Ruby's Gosu gem, a 2d graphics plugin. To do this, I have created a class called Window, which is intended to be inherited from (class Game: public Window), and then have three of its functions defined: `Update()` `Controls()` and `Draw()`.

To accomplish this in my window class I have a defined function `Show()` which looks like this

```
    void Window::Show(){
            // stuff to initialize and set up my window and controls
            glutTimerFunc(100,real_update,fps); 
    }
```

And my `real_update` function is simply

```
    void Window::real_update(int v){
            glutPostRedisplay();
            Update();
            glutTimerFunc(1000/fps,real_update,v);
    }
```

The logic here is that whatever class inherits `Window`, will be able to call `Show()`, which will set up the call back loop and initialize the window, then in the `real_update` loop it will call the `Update` which will be defined in the child class.

However, when I create a simple child class, define `Update` in the child class to just indicate it is being called, and then call Show on an instance of the child class it will only ever call the base class's (Window) definition for `Update`.

I'm certain this is a misunderstanding with inheritance, but I do not understand why. I thought that the child class call to `Show()` would call the base class's definition which then calls `Update`, which has been changed since the child class redefines it.

Comment: What are you class declarations?

Comment: My class Declarations are class Window  and class Game: public Window.
That is why I would expect Update to contain code written in Game and the function real_update to be inherited by Game and call Update when used int glutTimerFunct.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was found in this thread [Static Virtual functions in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291160/static-virtual-functions-in-c)

Essentially, you want to have virtual like behavior but because I want to call glut functions it must be static, so you template your class, and have it call the template classes update function.